# Map inside a Map

Tags: c++, dictionary, insert

The key string of _map represents the name of a film. 
The key int of the second map represent the year. And the string of the inside map representes all the translations of the film. I want to store more thant a translation per year and per film

```
map<string,map<int, string> > _map;
map<int, string>  _insideMap;
int year;
cin >> year;
_insideMap[int]="Los Vengadores";
_map["The Avengers"]=_mapaDins;
```

So after that I have to add another translation of the film The Avengers, in russian for example. 
So I do the same again  and the value Los Vengadores is replaced for "russian name" Also I have tried this but it doesn't work:

```
it2=_map.find("The Avengers");
it2.second.insert(2013,"russian translaiton");//erorr
```

How i have to do it the insert?

The Avengers ->

2010 Los Vengadorse

2013 "russian name"

next film ->

Thank oyu

Comment: So for the data in the inner map you want to store a *collection* of strings? Maybe a [*vector*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/containervector) would be good for that?

Comment: Your current solution only allows you to store one translation per year per film. Is this really what you want?

Comment: Use the map structure is obligated because the teachers says that is most efficient than a vector or a list for searching elements by the key.

Comment: No I want to store more thant one translation per year per film

Comment: This is probably right, but only for the outer map because it seems you don't search for the year. Why not use `map<string,vector<pair<year,string>>>`?

Comment: I mean you should have the translations as a vector, e.g. `map<string, map<int, vector<string>>>`.. Then just append new translations to the vector.

Comment: Any reason not to use a `std::multimap`?

Answer (score 0):

At first, insert should take a parameter with type pair, like this:

```
it2.second.insert( make_pair(2013,"russian translaiton")  );
```

and I think you need a multimap to store more than one translation per year per film.